# Spring Boot Admin: No option to refresh configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to integrate spring-boot-admin with an existing project which is using actuator and spring cloud config server. I am able to change the external property file and send a post request to **/refresh** endpoint from postman. It works fine and I can see updated value in client app. I have disabled all security for actuator endpoints for now to try spring-boot-admin. My problem is that, I can not see any option to change and refresh configuration in spring-boot-admin UI. I have created an issue but there is no update as of now so thought of sharing this problem here. All the details are available here. Does anyone have any idea what I have missed?

https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/1344

Before doing a downvote please have a look at the above link. Let me know if need any more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending few weekend hours and not getting any help from github issue (which was closed by giving some reason without being confirm if that is the case.), I found the problem. I was using external configuration and in one of such file **"app.cors"** was enabled which was preventing the Environment Manager to be displayed.

Comment: can you explain a little bit. I'm facing the same issue, but don't have any external configuration and didn't anything close of the *app.cors* you mentionned

Comment: The problem might also be related to the spring cloud version: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20509.
Adding management.endpoint.env.post.enabled: true into configuration should solve the problem.